# how to set text of <h4> from c# in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, bootstrap-modal

I have a popup created in bootstrap in my .aspx page.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">

     <div class="modal-title">
      <h4 id="modaltext" runat="server" class="modal-body"></h4>

     <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="show_loginpanel()" class="btn btn-primary">Okay</button>
      </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**In c# .cs file,**

```
modaltext.InnerHtml = "Successful";
```

**From c#, I am calling a js function which shows above modal popup.**

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "showModal();", true);
```

**JavaScript Function: showModal()**

```
function showModal() {

    $('#myModal').modal('show')

}
```

When I run my project, On popup there is no text displayed. `<h4>` tag is empty.

Can someone tell me what I am missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use LiteralControl for things like this:

```
<h4><asp:Literal id="SuccessfulLine" runat=server /></h4>
```

Code behind:

```
SuccessfulLine.Text ="Successful";
```

**EDIT:**

You can achieve that with javascript too:

```
string successfullString = "Successful";
string js = @"$( document ).ready(function() {

     $('#modaltext').text('" + successfullString + "')@
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
})";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", js , true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I made changes as you said but still text is empty.

Comment: @DKR from where you are calling showModal() method on document.ready ?

Comment: I am calling from c# on a button click with this: "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "showModal();", true);"

Comment: but showModal() is called with that statement, modal is poped up, button is displayed on popup, but there is no text.

Comment: @DKR what if you wrote the text in the html directly is it shown ?

Comment: yes. If I use this : <h4 id="modaltext" runat="server" class="modal-body">Success</h4>. It works. Text is displayed on popup.

Comment: @DKR in your showModal function write it with javascript your h4 content. 
$('#modaltext').text('Successful'); You can put the whole declaration of showModal() in code behind in document ready. I will write you how.

Comment: nice, it worked. :) Now I have to pass my message as parameter to showModal() while calling from c#. should be easy :) thanks :)